# Can I put a .gitmodules file in a subdirectory?

Tags: git, version-control, git-submodules

Let's say my repo index root is in `/project` dir.
Should the `.gitmodules` also be inside this dir, or can I put it into, say `/project/subdir`?

The reason I would like to do that is because I have multiple contributors and I want each to be responsible for his own set of submodules.

Answer (score 4):

`man gitsubmodule` on Debian Wheezy says:

```
...
SYNOPSIS
   $GIT_WORK_DIR/.gitmodules
...
```

According this default place for **.gitmodules** file is a top-level directory of the git working tree.
So, lets say you have such project structure:

```
project/
|
|--subproject-1/
|  `--.gitmodules
|--subproject-2/
|  `--.gitmodules
|--.gitmodules
```

**.gitmodules** in your project root dir will define modules **subproject-1** and **subproject-2**. Subprojects dependent modules also can be defined with **subproject-N/.gitmodules**, but those settings will affect only in proper subproject scope.

To update your project dependencies you should use command:

```
git submodule update
```

But if you want to update also dependencies of **subproject-1** and **subproject-2** use:

```
git submodule update --recursive
```